# How to remove rows that contains a repeating number pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like:

```
'a' 'b' 'c' 'd'
 0   1   2   3
 3   3   4   5
 9   8   8   8
```

and I want to remove rows that have a number that repeats more than once. So the answer is :

```
'a' 'b' 'c' 'd'
 0   1   2   3
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html) with compare length of columns ad filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.nunique(axis=1) == len(df.columns)]
print (df)
   'a'  'b'  'c'  'd'
0    0    1    2    3
```